# how to minimally connect MT-05 so that the LIN communication works

Tags: electronic-control-module

I have an MT05 (DELPHI-II) on the my desk. I tried to communicate with him via LIN, but he didn't answer.
I provide the following links: ground, power, ignition and LIN (image below).
When I connect the same MT-05 to a Kawasaki engine  (two connectors, J1 & J2) the communication is OK.
Please recommend me how to minimally connect MT-05 so that the LIN communication works.

[image]

Comment: What connectivity requirements does the MT05 manual suggest you need?

Comment: https://www.huntermotorcycles.com.au/dealer/Dealer%20info-%20website/Service%20and%20Predelivery%20info/Delphi%20Scan%20Tool%20Manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When reconnected, the testbench worked. It now works reliably and stably. Apparently the problem was in some one of the relationships. The sheme above is a working.